# failed date conversion in java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am seeing a string as Wed Apr 27 00:00:00 GMT-700 1988
and to convert it to date I did

```
Date dateOfBirth = new Date(bean.getUserProfileBean().getDateOfBirth());
```

This fails and  I am not sure why. Any idea if it is specific to GAE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to parse -700 the required format was Z,ZZ

Answer (score 1):

The date `Wed Apr 27 00:00:00 GMT-700 1988` is not in a format that Java can parse out of the box. Specifically, the timezone `GMT-700` part is not parsable by any library that I know of.

This format is not any of the standard timezone formats: [general timezone, RFC822 or ISO8601](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone).

You will need to write your own parser for that.

Comment: It should be probably GMT-7:00 (Thailand)

Answer (score 0):

Date has empty constructor or [`Date(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29)

If you want to get date from `String`, you need to use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
stirng strDate = bean.getUserProfileBean().getDateOfBirth();
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
  Locale.ENGLISH).parse(strDate );
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767/395659)

Alternatively you can try to use the [DateTimeFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) of Joda-Time, although you may encounter problems with the `'z'` for timezone names whih is conventional:

```
stirng strDate = bean.getUserProfileBean().getDateOfBirth();
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
dtf.parseDateTime(strDate);
```

Comment: getting Message:Invalid format: "Wed Apr 27 00:00:00 GMT-700 1988" is malformed at "GMT-700 1988"

Comment: Change the GMT-700 to GMT-7:00

Comment: i cant as it's coming from gae data store